# Change property type using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a decimal Value property in my domain class:

```
public class Domain
{
   public decimal Value {get;set}
}
```

I need to assign that Value property with two database values:

```
obj1.Value = decimal.Parse(reader["Value"].ToString());
obj2.Value = decimal.Parse(reader["Value2"].ToString());
```

Then I have a comparer method which compares these two properties:

```
public void Compare(List<object> Domains)
{
     //get properties with reflection

     //if the properties values are different I need to set a 'string' value [DIFFERENT]           to it.       
     prop.SetValue(comparableObj, "[DIFFERENT]", null);
}
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of a type-safe language.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

This just simply isn't possible.  The type of the property `Value` is set to `decimal` at compilation time and this cannot be changed at runtime.  Instead you need to focus on converting the `string` value into a `decimal` value.  That or picking a more suitable type for `Domain.Value`.

If you go the conversion route then I suggest looking at methods like [Convert.ToDecimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todecimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to change a property's type at runtime. I do know that if it were possible, it would be a bad idea.

You're better off having another field that you store the comparison result in. Then later when you need to use that "[DIFFERENT]" value, check the field that you stored the result in, and use that instead.

Comment: Dear Curtis, would you mind sharing a snippet code for that solution of yours? I believe that would be most fruitfull. Thank you